# Detecting NaN for number values in Freemarker

Tags: freemarker

Is there a way to detect a number (java double) being set to NaN in a Freemarker template?

Basically I'd like to do something like:

```
<#if val?is_nan>
  -
<#else>
   ${val}
</#if>
```

I tried to convert to string and then check for the `\uFFFD` character, but fail to do the correct compare here.

I have the impression that my problems come from the way, I give the data to the processing

```
            Map<String, Object> root = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            root.put("var", objectToRender);
            template.process(root, out);
```

Where `objectToRender` is the data structure I use. Perhaps I need to set some special flag for double handling?

Comment: `<#if fn?c == '\xFFFD'>NaN<#else>Not NaN</#if>` worked for me, however, I rather wouldn't build on NaN being formatted as '\uFFDD' by en-US `DecimalFormat` (i.e., by `?c`) forever. So I still recommend the `IsNaNMethod` solution below. And no, you shouldn't need to set any special flags. Doubles remain doubles by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.20 you can just write `val?is_nan`. For older versions, see below...

There's no `n?is_nan`, but you can create your own method that you can use as `isNaN(n)`:

```
import java.util.List;

import freemarker.template.TemplateBooleanModel;
import freemarker.template.TemplateMethodModelEx;
import freemarker.template.TemplateModelException;
import freemarker.template.TemplateNumberModel;

public class IsNaNMethod implements TemplateMethodModelEx {

    public static final IsNaNMethod INSTANCE = new IsNaNMethod();

    public Object exec(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") List args)
    throws TemplateModelException {
        if (args.size() != 1) {
            throw new TemplateModelException("isNaN needs exactly 1 arguments!");
        }

        Object arg = args.get(0);

        if (arg == null) {
            throw new TemplateModelException(
                    "The argument to the isNaN method must not be null!");
        }

        if (!(arg instanceof TemplateNumberModel)) {
            throw new TemplateModelException(
                    "The argument to the isNaN method must be a number! " +
                    "(The class of the value was: " + arg.getClass().getName() + ")");
        }

        Number n = ((TemplateNumberModel) arg).getAsNumber();
        if (n instanceof Double) {
            return ((Double) n).isNaN()
                    ? TemplateBooleanModel.TRUE : TemplateBooleanModel.FALSE;
        } else if (n instanceof Float) {
            return ((Float) n).isNaN()
                    ? TemplateBooleanModel.TRUE : TemplateBooleanModel.FALSE;
        } else {
            return TemplateBooleanModel.FALSE;
        }
    }

}
```

Put `IsNaNMethod.INSTANCE` into the data-model as "isNaN" (or into all data-models with `config.setSharderVariable`), or just pull it in in an `#include`-d/`#import`-ed template with `<#assign isNaN = "com.example.IsNaNMethod"?new()>`.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using a "workaround": in Java code I check if the value is NaN and then nullify the variable. For this I had to convert from `double` to `Double` type first.

```
if (Double.isNaN(var)
    var = null;
```

So `var` either has a non-NaN value or `null`

In the Freemarker template I process it like this:

```
<#if var?has_content>
   ${var}
<#else>
   NaN
</#if>
```

Not nice, but it works